# Add new column and populate with worksheet name using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

I'm trying to manipulate the code below to create a new column in the output and assign the sheetname in the new column.

```
$param = @{
    Path       = 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx'
    StartRow   = 5
    HeaderName = 'Property', 'Current settings', 'Proposed settings'
}

# foreach worksheet in this file
Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx' | ForEach-Object {
    # set the worksheetname name in $param
    $param['WorksheetName'] = $_.Name
    # import the worksheet and enumerate it
    foreach($line in Import-Excel @param) {
        $currSettings = $line.'Current settings'
        $propSettings = $line.'Proposed settings'
        # if the value of 'Current settings' cell is equal to the value of
        # 'Proposed settings' cell OR is empty / white spaces, skip it, go to next iteration
        if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings)) {
            continue
        }
        # if we're here, condition before this was not true, hence we want to
        # output this line
        $line
    }
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\Template\Changes.xlsx -AutoSize
```

The sheetname is already assigned to the $_.Name variable, but I would like to add it in a new column (A) next to all rows. For eg. every row taken from a particular sheet should have the sheetname in Column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property with `Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to recreate each object (`$line`) adding the `WorksheetName` property:

```
Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path 'C:\TEMP\Template\TemplateName.xlsx' | ForEach-Object {
    $param['WorksheetName'] = $_.Name
    foreach($line in Import-Excel @param) {
        $currSettings = $line.'Current settings'
        $propSettings = $line.'Proposed settings'
        if($currSettings -eq $propSettings -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currSettings)) {
            continue
        }
        $line | Select-Object @{N='WorksheetName';E={$param['WorksheetName']}}, *
    }
} | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\Template\Changes.xlsx -AutoSize
```

Alternatively, you can add the new property to the existing object, instead of recreating it, however this would add the property on last position (last Column in the Excel file):

```
# update the object
$line.PSObject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('WorksheetName', $_.Name))
# output the object, to be captured by `Export-Excel`
$line
```