# Powershell import of a CSV file with line break in the header

Tags: powershell, import-csv, xlsm

For a project i would need to export data from an .xlsm file data to a CSV file and then process it with powershell.
I do the export manually. In the original file, there are line breaks in the headers, which are also transferred to the CSV file.
My questions:

- Can I export a specific sheet from an .xlsm with Powershell?
- How can I replace the line breaks with spaces?

Attached is an example of what the original .xlsm file looks like.
[image]

Update: Unfortunately, I do not know how to upload a file.
Here is the content of an example CSV file:

```
Host name;Computer name old;IP-addr.;"IP-addr. 
free?";"Subnetmask 
CIDR Suffix";Static DNS entry;DNS alias;"vCPU Number 
[Units]";"RAM 
[GB]";"Boot disk 
[GB]";;;;;;;;
Broadcast;;172.225.145.0;Net;26;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Gateway;;172.225.145.1;Net;26;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Server125;;172.225.145.2;yes;26;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Server126;;172.225.145.3;yes;26;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Server127;;172.225.145.4;yes;26;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Server128;;172.225.145.5;no;26;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Screenshot from Notepad++ of the CSV file

[image: Screenshot from Notepad++ of the CSV file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I export a specific sheet from an .xlsm with Powershell?

Use the [`ImportExcel` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel), which you can install with `Install-Module ImportExcel`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71898337/45375) for an example.

> How can I replace the line breaks with spaces?

A simple - though not efficient - approach is to:

- Import the CSV with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) or `Import-Excel` (from the `ImportExcel` module) first - which works fine with header fields that have embedded line breaks, as long as such fields are enclosed in `"..."`
- Then process the resulting `[pscustomobject]` instances and replace them with a newly constructed variant whose property names have the line breaks replaced with spaces.

```
Import-Csv yourFile.csv | # parse the CSV file into [pscustomobject]s
  ForEach-Object {        # process each object
    $oht = [ordered] @{} # create an aux. ordered hashtable
    foreach ($p in $_.psobject.Properties) { # loop over the object's properties 
     # add a name-value entry with the modified column (property) name.
      $oht[($p.Name -replace '\s+', ' ')] = $p.Value
    }
    [pscustomobject] $oht # convert the hashtable to [pscustomobject] and output
  }
```

Pipe the above to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) or `Export-Excel` (from the `ImportExcel` module) in order to re-export the data back to a file,  pipe it to another command, or capture the transformed objects in a variable (`$objects = Import-Csv ...`)

Note:

- [`-replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) is used to replace any non-empty run (`+`) of whitespace characters. (`\s`) with a single space (`' '`). This ensures that the sequence `<space><LF>` is replaced with a single space.